# TPCL - toshiba Label printer langauge - how to print Nordic character

Tags: label, printer-control-language

Can someone please tell me how to print Nordic characters in TPCL language for Label Printing.

Below is my code.

```
{D1546,1018,1526|}
{C|}
{D1546,1270,1526|}
{AX;+000,+000,+00|}
{AY;+00,0|}
{PV01;0200,0125,0100,0100,B,00,B|}
{RV01;ÄÜöüä|}
{XS;I,0001,0002C5000|}
```

I am trying to print the nordic characters but they are not get printed correctly.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `PC` command with the **H** font type. See example below:

```
{PC02;0350,0110,05,05,H,00,B=ÄÜöüä|}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, pls make sure the printer got the charset configured correctly