# TEC Label Printer - Printing German character ÄÖÜöäüß

Tags: label

need help regarding some Nordic / german characters with TEC label printer (Toshiba).
below is my code (TPCL - TEC - Command language)

```
{D1546,1018,1526|}
{C|}
{D1546,1270,1526|}

{AX;+000,+000,+00|}
{AY;+00,0|}

{PC01;0200,0125,3,3,B,00,B|}
{RC01;TESTÄÖßöüä|}

{XS;I,0001,0002C5000|}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TPCL - toshiba Label printer langauge - how to print Nordic character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76681602/tpcl-toshiba-label-printer-langauge-how-to-print-nordic-character)